# Google Script to transfer Data from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, data-transfer

I'm hoping someone will lend me a hand with a writing a Google Script to be used on Google Sheets (unless it can be done with a standard formula string).

I would like a script to Search for a specific "text value" in a specified column of "Sheet1", if "text value" is found, data from that "Row" is transferred to "Sheet2" in the First available **empty** Row. Then, after the data is transferred to "Sheet2", the row with data from "Sheet1" is deleted.

*Note, "Sheet2" has fewer Headers than "Sheet1". I only want Data from "sheet1" that has the same Headers as "sheet2"
Here is a sample workbook.[Data Transfer](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CyT3z6_JNJpUDcZdBUU4EyP_W_1KtCHwJe5AlYdCz_Y/edit?usp=sharing) If "text" in column F is "lost", transfer data from that row into "sheet2" but ONLY data relevant to headers in "sheet2".

I'm new to Scripts and VBA and would appreciate any help someone is willing to lend.

Thank you very much in advance!

-Jesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find, Move and Delete**

`txt` is the text to search for

`col` is the column name to search in

```
function findMoveDelete(txt,col) {
  var txt=txt||'Hoover';//search text
  var col=col||'Location';//column name
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var dHdrToIdx={dhA:[]};
  dHdrToIdx.dhA=dsh.getRange(1,1,1,dsh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  dHdrToIdx.dhA.forEach(function(hdr,i){dHdrToIdx[hdr]=i;});
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var sHdrToIdx={shA:[]};
  sHdrToIdx.shA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  sHdrToIdx.shA.forEach(function(hdr,i){sHdrToIdx[hdr]=i;});
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    //Find
    if(vA[i][sHdrToIdx[col]]==txt) {
      var row=[];
      dHdrToIdx.dhA.forEach(function(dhdr,j){
        row.push(vA[i][sHdrToIdx[dHdrToIdx.dhA[j]]]);
      });
      dsh.appendRow(row);//Move
      sh.deleteRow(i+2-d++);//Delete
    }
  }
}
```

Sheets 1 and 2 after run:

[image]

[image]

You must have the same headers in sheet1 and sheet2.  You can put them in any order you like but they must be the same in both sheets.

Comment: Thank you very much Cooper! I ran the script and it almost works for me. It finds the specified txt and deletes the entire row perfectly! However, it does not move that row to Sheet2. Can you please advise?

Comment: I just tried it with your data and it works for me.

Comment: Did you put the column headers in the first row of  Sheet2.  They need to be there exactly like they are in your example. Don't change the names in any way because the code will have to change as well.  It's actually okay to change the names as long as they are the same on sheet1 and sheet2.

Comment: If you didn't get anything it was probably because they couldn't find the right columns to put them in because either that names were not there or you changed them.

Comment: Cooper, I'm not sure but I must have done something wrong. I tried again this morning and I was getting a couple of errors but now it's working perfectly. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'm trying to use the script on this spreadsheet but I'm getting an error on line 8. Any advise? I've tried to figure it out on my own but am struggling on why it's getting an error on this woorkbook but not on the other one. 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iydah3Gm6O0Xd70kRZgO9DAMBrSW6i-YoNBES2p-h7E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WB2gl9jSZ_meXhyxEI2Mo3AS55Khc3E0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'd guess that the error is Cannot find method getRange of null and I'm guessing that it's because your var dsh is null.  So make sure that you have the correct sheet name with no extra spaces and if that's true then I'd recommend removing all the spaces in the name and replace with underscore.   I'm guessing that possibly object properties can't have spaces in them.  I don't know that for a fact. I'll go check it out.

Comment: I verified name was exact (did a copy and paste). Also made sure no spaces or extra spaces. It still gives error. When I change sheet names to Sheet1 and Sheet2. It works fine. I changed name to 2020_Active/Propects and it works perfectly. Thank you again Cooper.